# How to make a launcher that will first navigate to a folder and then execute a command that resides in normal  /usr/bin/

Tags: 12.04, launcher, shortcuts, google-drive, grive

Okay this Question is basically directed for using **GRIVE** the linux client for **Google Drive**

Details on how to do it are [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html).

The thing is that,evrytime i want the folder to sync,I have to navigate to the google drive folder and then execute the `grive` commnd.

I want to make it simple..I want to make a launcher(I know how to make a *.desktop file).
But in a .desktop file you always give path to executable file(generally .sh).

Here,there is no script in the Grive folder.The app is as usual in `/usr/bin/grive`

Now how do I make the launcher to first navigate to the grive folder and then execut the grive command..

Thanx :)

Comment: @virpara..Plz have a look at this..I belive you have the solution.. ;) thanx.!

Comment: @virpara..Got the answer.. :p izx help me.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.desktop` file, set

`Exec=sh -c "cd /path/to/directory/to/sync && grive"`

and set `Terminal=true`

Comment: Not working...It says `Exec=sh` no such file or directory

Comment: oops...sorry...it worked...my rong...i cpied the `Exe=` along with the other thing and added it afte `Exec=` again.. :p...sorry..n thanx..!! ;)

Comment: yup...will be allowed to do it in 2min ;P